# Android app issues

Tags: android, exception, button

I'm trying to develop an android calculator, and although Android Studio doesn't show there are any errors in my code, when I run the app and try to click a button, it stops working. In this case I clicked the 8 button (with the ID button8, linked to the onClick1 method when clicked)

Android studio throws the following exception code when I press the 8 button:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.st1.u3141294.sparkscientificcalculator, PID: 2125
              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onClick1 (sparkMain)(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button8'
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22260)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
Application terminated.
```

Here is my main class code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.text.Html;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.*;
import android.app.Activity;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class sparkMain extends AppCompatActivity {

//TODO: Parentheses; first press enters first parenthesis, second press closes parentheses
//TODO: Long press Sin (gives cos, tan, sin-1, cos-1, tan-1) and log gives log-1

protected void onCreateView() {
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.buttonXPow)).setText(Html.fromHtml("X<sup><Small>y</small><s/up>"));
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.button10Pow)).setText(Html.fromHtml("10<sup><Small>y</small><s/up>"));
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.spark_activity_main);
    onCreateView();

}

ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
String stringInput = "";
String stringOutput = "";

public void onClick1 (View v) {
    TextView textViewCalcHistExp1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCalcHistExp1);
    Button button = (Button) v;
    stringInput = (String) button.getText().toString();

    if (!stringInput.contains("+") && !stringInput.contains("-") && !stringInput.contains("×") && !stringInput.contains("÷")) {
        stringOutput = stringOutput+stringInput;
        if (arrayList.size()>0) {
            arrayList.remove((arrayList.size()-1));
        }
        arrayList.add(stringOutput);
    }
    else{
        arrayList.add(stringInput);
        arrayList.add(stringInput);
        stringOutput="";
    }
    //This version truncates array formatting i.e. entering "2+4*6" would display "2+4*6"
    textViewCalcHistExp1.setText(textViewCalcHistExp1.getText().toString()+stringInput);

    //This version leaves array formatting i.e. entering "2+4*6" would display [2,+,4,*,6] ;good for debugging
    //textViewCalcHistExp1.setText(arrayList.toString());
}

public void onClick (View v) {

    TextView textViewCalcHistRes1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewCalcHistRes1);
    int calc = 0;
    int c = arrayList.size();

    //i.e. array [2,+,3,*,4,-,3] size(c) = 7, so [2,+,3,*,4,-,3]
    while (c!=1) {
        if (c>3) {
            if (arrayList.get(3).contains("×") || arrayList.get(3).contains("÷")) {
                if (arrayList.get(3).contains("×")){calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2))*Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(4));}
                if (arrayList.get(3).contains("÷")){calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2))/Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(4));}

                //calc = 12 ;array = [2,+,3,*,4,-,3]
                arrayList.remove(2); //[2,+,*,4,-,3]
                arrayList.remove(2); //[2,+,4,-,3]
                arrayList.remove(2); //[2,+,-,3]
                arrayList.add(2,Integer.toString(calc)); //[2,+,12,-,3]
                c = arrayList.size(); // size(c) = 5
            }
            else {
                //[2,+,12,-,3]
                if (arrayList.get(3).contains("+")){calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0))+Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));}
                if (arrayList.get(3).contains("-")){calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0))-Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));}
                if (arrayList.get(3).contains("×")){calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0))*Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));}
                if (arrayList.get(3).contains("÷")){calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0))/Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));}
                //calc = 14
                arrayList.remove(0); //[+,12,-,3]
                arrayList.remove(0); //[12,-,3]
                arrayList.remove(0); //[-,3]
                arrayList.add(0,Integer.toString(calc)); //[14,-,3]
                c = arrayList.size(); // size(c) = 3
            }
        }
        // size(c) <= 3
        else {
            if (arrayList.get(3).contains("+")){calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0))+Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));}
            if (arrayList.get(3).contains("-")){calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0))-Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));}
            if (arrayList.get(3).contains("×")){calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0))*Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));}
            if (arrayList.get(3).contains("÷")){calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0))/Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));}
            //calc = 11
            arrayList.remove(0); //[-,3]
            arrayList.remove(0); //[3]
            arrayList.remove(0); //[null]
            arrayList.add(0,Integer.toString(calc)); // [9]
            c = arrayList.size(); // size(c) = 1
        }
    }
    textViewCalcHistRes1.setText(Integer.toString(calc));
    arrayList.clear();

}

public String backspace (String str) {
    if (stringOutput != null && stringOutput.length() > 0) {
        stringOutput = stringOutput.substring(0, stringOutput.length()-1);
    }
    return str;
}

}
```

And spark_activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app2="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/spark_activity_main"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.st1.u3141294.sparkscientificcalculator.sparkMain"
android:weightSum="2"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
    style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.ScrollView"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:fillViewport="false"

    android:layout_height="260dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutScroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/textViewCalcHistExp1"
            android:layout_height="55dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/textViewCalcHistRes1"
            android:layout_height="55dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/firstLinearHorizontal">

        <Button
            android:text="log"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonLog"
            android:background="@drawable/operator_style"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textColor="@drawable/operator_style"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:text="√"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonSqrt"
            android:background="@drawable/operator_style"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textColor="@drawable/operator_style"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:text="10^y"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/button10Pow"
            android:background="@drawable/operator_style"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textColor="@drawable/operator_style"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:text="X^y"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/buttonXPow"
            android:background="@drawable/operator_style"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textColor="@drawable/operator_style"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonDel"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/operator_style"
            app2:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_input_delete_black_trans" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp">

        <Button
            android:text="sin"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonSin"
            android:background="@drawable/operator_style"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textColor="@drawable/operator_style"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:text="π"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonPi"
            android:background="@drawable/operator_style"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textColor="@drawable/operator_style"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:text="( )"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonPar"
            android:background="@drawable/operator_style"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textColor="@drawable/operator_style"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:text="+/-"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonSign"
            android:background="@drawable/operator_style"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textColor="@drawable/operator_style"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:text="÷"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonDiv"
            android:background="@drawable/operator_style"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textColor="@drawable/operator_style"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick1 (sparkMain)" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp">

        <Button
            android:text="7"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textColor="@drawable/button_style"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick1 (sparkMain)" />

        <Button
            android:text="8"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textColor="@drawable/button_style"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick1 (sparkMain)" />

        <Button
            android:text="9"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textColor="@drawable/button_style"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick1 (sparkMain)" />

        <Button
            android:text="×"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonMult"
            android:background="@drawable/operator_style"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textColor="@drawable/operator_style"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.735"
            android:onClick="onClick1 (sparkMain)" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp">

        <Button
            android:text="4"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textColor="@drawable/button_style"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:onClick="onClick1 (sparkMain)" />

        <Button
            android:text="5"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textColor="@drawable/button_style"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:onClick="onClick1 (sparkMain)" />

        <Button
            android:text="6"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textColor="@drawable/button_style"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:onClick="onClick1 (sparkMain)" />

        <Button
            android:text="-"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonSub"
            android:background="@drawable/operator_style"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textColor="@drawable/operator_style"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.735"
            android:onClick="onClick1 (sparkMain)" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp">

        <Button
            android:text="1"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textColor="@drawable/button_style"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:onClick="onClick1 (sparkMain)" />

        <Button
            android:text="2"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textColor="@drawable/button_style"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:onClick="onClick1 (sparkMain)" />

        <Button
            android:text="3"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textColor="@drawable/button_style"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:onClick="onClick1 (sparkMain)" />

        <Button
            android:text="+"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonAdd"
            android:background="@drawable/operator_style"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textColor="@drawable/operator_style"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.735"
            android:onClick="onClick1 (sparkMain)" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="36dp">

        <Button
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:id="@+id/button0"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textColor="@drawable/button_style"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:onClick="onClick1 (sparkMain)" />

        <Button
            android:text="."
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonDec"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textColor="@drawable/button_style"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp" />

        <Button
            android:text="="
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonEqual"
            android:background="#f49542"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_weight="1.78"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:onClick="onClick (sparkMain)" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any ideas as to why it's throwing exceptions on such a simple action?

Comment: please share your spark_activity_main xml

Comment: My bad, edited the OP

Comment: May I ask where you learned that `onClick1 (sparkMain)` is the correct syntax?

Comment: I didn't, it's what Android Studio appended to each button's xml block when I selected their onClick action in the design view for the layout. I didn't bother checking the xml as I thought Android Studio would use the correct syntax the first time around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In your xml,**

```
android:onClick="onClick1 (sparkMain)"
```

cause the problem. Please change

```
android:onClick="onClick1 (sparkMain)"
```

to

```
android:onClick="onClick1"
```

It will resolve the problem.

Comment: Your answer is correct, and although Phan Van Linh posted first I thought you should get the rep, seeing as Phan has no shortage of rep.

Answer (score 2):

In your XML file. Simply change

```
android:onClick="onClick1 (sparkMain)"
```

to

```
android:onClick="onClick1"
```

Also, you can check [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) to see the correct way to implements on click in button

Comment: Just did this, still throws the exception

Comment: make sure you change all of theme in xml file. then if it still happend, please share the new logcat for me

Comment: I did and at first it wasn't working, but then I clicked Run again and it works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your app is throwing FATAL Exception. Exceptions are not detected at compile time but instead they are encountered at run time. You have defined attribute android:onClick in your xml and the method you assigned in that was not found. Try changing the name of method or I think you should use OnClickListener(). That will definately help you.

Just Google how to implement onClickListeners for button in android.